# Template static member definition depends on order passed to linker

Tags: c++, templates, linker, g++

The following code, which has 2 definitions for a template static field member, each definition defines `template1<int>::x` with a different value.

One would expect the linker to reject such redefinitions as they have different values.

But compilation & linkage passes for both g++ and MSVC, and which definition is used is dependent on the order in which the sources are passed to the linker.

Is this behavior compliant to the C++ standard, undefined behavior, or a linker bug?

**my_template.h**

```
template <class T>
class template1
{
public:
    static int x;
};
```

**Src2.cpp**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "my_template.h"

template <class T>
int template1<T>::x = 2; 

void my_func() // definition
{
    printf("my_func: template1<int>::x = %d\n", template1<int>::x); // definition of X to 2.
    printf("my_func: template1<char>::x = %d\n", template1<char>::x); // definition of X to 2.
}
```

**Main.cpp**

```
#include <cstdio>
#include "my_template.h"

template <class T>
int template1<T>::x = 1;

void my_func();

int main()
{
    printf("main: template1<int>::x = %d\n", template1<int>::x); // definition of X to 1.
    my_func();
    return 0;
}
```

Compile with g++ (MinGW.org GCC Build-20200227-1) 9.2.0+

**Compile1**

```
g++ -o prog Src2.cpp Main.cpp
```

**Output1**

```
main: template1<int>::x = 2
my_func: template1<int>::x = 2
my_func: template1<char>::x = 2
```

**Compile2**

```
g++ -o prog Main.cpp Src2.cpp
```

**Ouput2**

```
main: template1<int>::x = 1
my_func: template1<int>::x = 1
my_func: template1<char>::x = 2
```

Observed also with

```
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.25.28612 for x86
```

When I disassembled the code with `-S` flag, each compilation unit defined the same symbol name.

Co-work with [Nightra](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1796269/nightra).

Comment: FWIW, if you have C++17 you can use `static inline int x = 2;` in the class to not even have to worry about defining the member outside the class.  Pre C++17, since the definition is a template, you can move that into the header file after the class since all templates are implicitly inline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this behavior compliant to the C++ standard, undefined behavior, or a linker bug?

This is undefined behaviour (UB).

---

From [[basic.def.odr]/4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.def.odr#4) of [N4659](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/) [**emphasis** mine]:

> Every program shall contain **exactly one definition of every
>   non-inline** function or **variable that is odr-used in that program**
>   outside of a discarded statement; **no diagnostic required**. The
>   definition can appear explicitly in the program, it can be found in
>   the standard or a user-defined library, or (when appropriate) it is
>   implicitly defined (see [class.ctor], [class.dtor] and [class.copy]).
>   An inline function or variable shall be defined in every translation
>   unit in which it is odr-used outside of a discarded statement.

Non-`constexpr` `static` member variables of templates are *not* implicitly `inline`, and thus this is UB, no diagnostic required.

We may also turn to [[basic.def.odr]/6](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.def.odr#6) for an even stronger statement (not even requiring ODR-use) [quoting a selected extract, **emphasis** mine]:

> There can be more than one definition of a [...] **static data member
>   of a class template** [...] in a program provided that each definition
>   appears in a different translation unit, and **provided the
>   definitions satisfy the following requirements**. Given such an entity
>   named `D` defined in more than one translation unit, then
>
> - each definition of `D` shall consist of the same sequence of tokens; and
>
> [...]
>
> If the definitions of `D` satisfy all these requirements, **then the
>   behavior is as if there were a single definition of `D`**. If the
>   definitions of `D` do not satisfy these requirements, **then the
>   behavior is undefined**.

With two *different* definitions of `D` (in your case, `template1<int>::x`) *"each definition of `D` shall consist of the same sequence of tokens"* is not fulfilled, and it follows that we naturally cannot possibly fulfill *"[...] as if there were a single definition of `D`"*; thus UB.

Answer (score 5):

This violates [ODR](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition) (which requires that an entity must have *exactly* one definition, if it's used). So the program has UB.

The compiler *couldn't* diagnose this, because each translation unit is fine. In theory, the linker *could* diagnose this, but in practice it won't do that.

Comment: This occurs only with templates, using global variables, it doesn't pass linkage.

Comment: Maybe so, but it's still UB. Is your question, "why does the linker diagnose one, but not the other?"